# Need a help in Java Class onClickListener() and switch(v.getId)

Tags: java, android, class

I'm making a simple CardView dashboard by following Youtube Tutorial.
Everything was going smooth until I tried to set an onClickListener to the view.

When I tried to access the variable on CardView definition on the onCreate method, it is accessing the id on my activity_main.xml instead.

The editor keeps showing Red mark when I tried to access the Definition variable.

I usually use android:onClick instead of using a one-click listener, as I'm very new with these programming things, I'd like to try something new.

this is my java activity_main Class

```
package com.budiluhur.mylibrary;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public CardView katalog;
    public CardView updateKatalog;
    public CardView help;
    public CardView exit;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        katalog = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.Katalog);
        updateKatalog = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.UpdateKatalog);
        help = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.Help);
        exit = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.Exit);

        //Listener
        katalog.setOnClickListener(this);
        updateKatalog.setOnClickListener(this);
        help.setOnClickListener(this);
        exit.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        Intent i;
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.updateKatalog:
                i = new Intent(this, KatalogBuku.class);
                break;


            default:
                break;
        }


    }

}
```

and this is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#fcfcfc"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/ll">

    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/Katalog"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlebackgroundpurple"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_katalog"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Katalog"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightGrey"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Check Katalog Buku"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/UpdateKatalog"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlebackgroundyellow"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_update_library" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Update Katalog"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightGrey"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Update Katalog Buku"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/Help"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlebackgroundgreen"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_help_black_24dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                    android:text="Help"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightGrey"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Bantuan Aplikasi"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/Exit"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlebackgroundaccent"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Exit"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightGrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Keluar Aplikasi"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

what I'm trying to access is 'updateKatalog' in the onCreate Class, not UpdateKatalog which located on the XML File.

seeking for your helpful answer.

Comment: Where is the problem, exactly? In the `switch`? If so, `case R.id.updateKatalog:` needs to be `case R.id.UpdateKatalog:`, uppercase `U`, as that's how you've defined it in the layout XML.

Comment: hi Mike, Thank you so much for your reply. it works!
i thought that R.id is referring to 'updateKatalog'. i just realized that it's referring to the id on the xml. thanks a lot Mike! @MikeM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout xml file you are defining the ID as "@+id/UpdateKatalog"

In your FindViewByID method, also calling it R.id.UpdateKatalog

But in your case statement you are using case R.id.updateKatalog:

You need to uppercase the U in UpdateKatalog

Comment: Hi Michael, yes you're 100% correct. i thought it's referring to 'updateKatalog' variable, because i've defined the 'UpdateKatalog' as updateKatalog in 'onCreate' class. thanks for helping me out!